# Autofocus con JavaScript o HTML

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Hola estoy trabajando en un formulario, y queria saber si me pueden ayudar con el tema de "autofocus con JavaScript o HTML (en su defecto). El punto es que al crear un formulario simple si consigo dar el foco al campo que quiero (dni en este caso), pero estoy usando bootstrap, especificamente la "class = collapse", y cuando doy click en la misma se despliega el formulario; una vez que se muestra dicho formulario no se activa el foco (focus() o autofocus (en html))

La cuestión es que probe con muchas opciones que encontré en internet (comentadas en el código, o algunos las borré). Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar. Aqui subo el código

```
    <div class="container">  
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="card">
             <div class="card-header" id="first" style="background: #cfcfcf;">
              <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
               <strong> Paciente que visita por primera vez.</strong>
              </a>
            </div>
             <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" style="background: #cadee0;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="lab row justify-content-center mb-1"><h4>Signos, síntomas y antecedentes</h4></div> 
                 <div class="alert alert-info">                 

                        <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="response.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">          
                                    <div class="form-group row">                       
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label class="lab">Dni:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="Ingresar dni del paciente" required autofocus> 
                                        </div>                                              
                                    </div>      
                                    <div class="form-group row">                       
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label class="lab">nombre:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="" required> 
                                        </div>                                              
                                    </div>    

                                    <select id="mySelect">
                                      <option>Option 1</option>
                                      <option>Option 2</option>
                                    </select>               
                        </form>
                 </div> 
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <script>
    var hasAutofocus = document.getElementById('dni').autofocus;
    console.log(hasAutofocus);
    // traemos TODOS aquellos que tienen fomulario como nombre (si tenemos mas de uno no es aconsejable o ver el array)
    /*const formulario = document.getElementsByName('formulario')[0],
          elementos = formulario.elements;  
    function getFocus() {
        document.getElementById("dni").focus();
       }
    //const elementPrim = elementos[0]; 
     elementos[0].setAttribute('autofocus' , 'focus()'); 
     const elementPrim = elementos;
    console.log(elementPrim);

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("dni").focus();
        };*/
</script>
```

**Aqui agrego lo nuevo que hice, con eso logré que se coloque el focus pero cuando se esconde el formulario, no entiendo porque no lo hace cuando lo despliega. Finalmente intente poniendo el getElementById.focus() tanto por el tru y por el false, pero sigue comportandose de la misma manera. **

```
!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'> 
        <!-- https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet -> DESCARGAR LOS ICONOS DESPUES PARA NO USARLOS DESDE INTERNET -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <div class="container">  
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="card" >
             <div class="card-header" id="first" style="background: #cfcfcf;" >
              <a class="card-link" id="aColaps" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" onclick="myFunction()" >
               <strong> Paciente que visita por primera vez.</strong>
              </a>
            </div>
             <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" style="background: #cadee0;" >
              <div class="card-body" >
                <div class="lab row justify-content-center mb-1"><h4>Signos, síntomas y antecedentes</h4></div> 
                 <div class="alert alert-info">                 

                        <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="response.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >          
                                    <div class="form-group row">                       
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label class="lab">Dni:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="Ingresar dni del paciente" onkeypress="return typeNumber(event)" onpaste="return false" required autofocus> 
                                        </div>                                              
                                    </div>      
                                    <div class="form-group row">                       
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                                        <label class="lab">nombre:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="" required> 
                                        </div>                                              
                                    </div>    

                                    <select id="mySelect">
                                      <option>Option 1</option>
                                      <option>Option 2</option>
                                    </select>               
                        </form>
                 </div> 
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <script>

    function myFunction() {
    var elto;
        var hasAutofocus = document.getElementById('aColaps');
        elto = hasAutofocus.className;
    //var clas = 'card-link collapsed';
        //console.log(typeof elto);
        //console.log(typeof clas);

        if(elto === 'card-link'){
            document.getElementById("dni").focus();
            //onsole.log('si');
        }else{
            document.getElementById("dni").focus();
            //console.log('no');
        }


    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Aplica `document.getElementById("dni").focus();` justo después de mostrar el formulario, según dices, está oculto y de nada sirve ponerle foco, porque al dar clic en cualquier otro espacio lo va a perder, como cuando haces clic en el enlace que muestra el formulario.

Comment: Claro, es correcto lo que me dices, lo que pasa es que no estoy pudiendo lograr que se ejecute el focus justo cuando se muestra el formulario; Cuando doy click en el div de clase "collapse" cambia a "collapse show", pero no consiguiendo que lo tome a ese cambio como para que se de cuenta de ejecutar el focus(). Probe tambien con el onCLick a ese div, pero nada. Le puse un onclick = "myFunction(), y en el script function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dni").focus();
}

Comment: Si muestras ese código va a ser más fácil tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: hice lo siguiente:
function myFunction() {
var elto;
 var hasAutofocus = document.getElementById('aColaps');
 elto = hasAutofocus.className;
if(elto === 'card-link collapsed'){
  document.getElementById("dni").focus();
  //onsole.log('si');
 }else{
  document.getElementById("dni").focus();
  //console.log('no');
 }
Logre que se coloque el focus() pero cuando se contrae, digamos, cuando se despliega el formulario no se coloca el focus, si doy click y se contrae mientras se va cerrando se coloca el focus en el campo dni, probe hasta poniendolo sin importar la comparacion y aun nada

Comment: Ahi comparti el código que estoy manejando en este instante.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para agregar código y, por favor, agrega el código que usas para mostrar el formulario, es ahí donde tiene que aplicarse el focus.

Comment: Ya lo hice, no sabia que podia editarlo de esa forma, soy nuevo en la plataforma. Gracias por eso.

Comment: No es necesario que pongas todo tu código nuevamente y, de hecho, no pusiste cómo haces para mostrar el modal, eso es lo que se necesita para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es de concepto. Trataré de aclarar un poco las cosas en mi respuesta.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea establecer el enfoque (*focus*) a un elemento de un formulario. El formulario está oculto al momento de la carga del DOM, y se muestra al hacer clic sobre un botón.

Se utiliza el *Framework* CSS [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) para los estilos del documento, y específicamente el *plugin* [`Collapse`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#how-it-works) de dicho Framework.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tu intentos parte de añadir una función al evento `click` del elemento usando la propiedad [`onClick()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick):

```
<elemento onclick="myFunction()"></elemento>
```

El problema de esto, es que Bootstrap se hace cargo de añadir los manejadores de eventos para nuestros elementos para poder crear los efectos de animación y poder así mostrar / ocultar un elemento.

Por otro lado, cuando haces `click` sobre el botón (o en tu caso sobre el elemento *anchor* `<a>`), dicha acción se ejecuta inmediatamente, sin esperar a que las acciones de Bootstrap terminen de hacer su trabajo, por lo cual el formulario aún no es visible cuando se le aplica el enfoque a uno de sus elementos.

Tomando eso en cuenta, y leyendo la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#events) sobre los eventos que podemos capturar en un elemento de tipo `Collapse`, vemos que hay 2 eventos que podríamos usar para logar lo que nos proponemos:

1. `show.bs.collapse`: se dispara inmediatamente cuando se llama al método de instancia `show`.
2. `shown.bs.collapse`: se dispara cuando un elemento de tipo `Collapse` es totalmente visible por el usuario y todos los estilos se han aplicado sobre el mismo.

El segundo método es el que vamos a usar, ya que nos garantiza que el formulario ya es totalmente visible y podemos establecer el enfoque a alguno de sus elementos.

El código podría quedar parecido al siguiente:

```js
//Función para establecer el foco al elemento "dni"

const setFocusDNI = (event) => {
  $('#dni').focus();
}

// Añadimos nuestra función para manejar el evento del elemento tipo `Collapse`
$('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', setFocusDNI);
```

```html
<!-- Estilos de Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">  
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card" >
       <div class="card-header" id="first" style="background: #cfcfcf;" >
        <a class="card-link" id="aColaps" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"> <!-- No hace falta usar 'onclick' -->
         <strong> Paciente que visita por primera vez.</strong>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" style="background: #cadee0;" >
        <div class="card-body" >
          <div class="lab row justify-content-center mb-1"><h4>Signos, síntomas y antecedentes</h4></div> 
            <div class="alert alert-info">
              <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="response.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >          
                <div class="form-group row">                       
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label class="lab">Dni:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="Ingresar dni del paciente" onkeypress="return typeNumber(event)" onpaste="return false" required autofocus> 
                  </div>                                              
                </div>      
                <div class="form-group row">                       
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <label class="lab">nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="" required> 
                  </div>                                              
                </div>    
                <select id="mySelect">
                  <option>Option 1</option>
                  <option>Option 2</option>
                </select>               
              </form>
            </div> 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Scripts de Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Como puedes ver, simple y limpio. Sin usar la propiedad `onclick` de HTML, ni añadir eventos al hacer clic sobre el botón.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el aporte, soy nuevo en este tipo de eventos. La explicacion estuvo muy buena, clara y la entendí bien. Nuevamente muchas gracias.